# Save Option on Database

Tags: php, html, customization, options

Sorry for the question but can you help me? I have this form in a widget:

```
<form> 
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Counter Position:</legend>
  </br>
  <p> 
   Right  <input type="radio" name="position" value="right"/>
  <p>  
   Left  <input type="radio" name="position" value="left"/>
  <p>
   Center  <input type="radio" name="position" value="center"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

how to save on database the option selected?

Comment: is this a form for the widget admin page - or front-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php add_option( $option, $value, $deprecated, $autoload ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option

```
global $options;
?>
<form action="options.php" method="post">
  <?php $settings = get_option('options');
  ?>
  <?php settings_fields('theme_options'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Counter Position:</legend>
        </br>
        <p>
            Right <input type="radio" name="position" value="right"/>
        <p>
            Left <input type="radio" name="position" value="left"/>
        <p>
            Center <input type="radio" name="position" value="center"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php


function r_set()
{
  register_setting('theme_options', 'options', 'validate_options');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'r_set');
function validate_options($value)
{
  global $sa_options;
  $val['position'] = $value['position'];
  return $val;
}
```

Comment: thanks, how to use for save the radio selected from users??

Comment: check my edit..